# How is DOM XSS possible here?

Tags: xss, dom

I was looking at this website and trying to understand how this XSS is possible, but I just can't figure it out. Here's the URL: http://www.domxss.com/domxss/01_Basics/05_jquery_html.html?681973661

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
function setMessage(){
    var t=location.hash.slice(1);
    $("div[id="+t+"]").html("Message from the name "+window.name);
}
$(document).ready(setMessage);
</script>
<span>
    <a href="#message" > Show Here</a>
    <div id="message">Showing Message1</div>
</span>
<span>
    <a href="#message1" > Show Here</a>
    <div id="message1">Showing Message2</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This page is taking input from an untrusted source, and directly outputs it in the browser as HTML.

In this case, the untrusted source is `window.name`. To the inexperienced programmer, this may seem harmless, but in reality, it can be set to any arbitrary value, because it's derived from the name of the frame:

```
<iframe
    src="http://www.domxss.com/domxss/01_Basics/05_jquery_html.html?681973661#message"
    name="<script>alert(0)</script>"
></iframe>
```

In the code you've given, there's another glaring hole: The selector is also taken from an untrusted source (the URL), which allows attackers to output the HTML in whatever place they desire. This doesn't need to be a frame, just visit the following URL:

```
http://www.domxss.com/domxss/01_Basics/05_jquery_html.html?681973661#whatever],body,[whatever
```

`t` is set to `"whatever],body,[whatever"` (from `location.hash`), and is used to construct a jQuery selector (`"div[id="+t+"]"`). Together, it results in a selector that selects (e.g.) the `<body>` element:

```
"div[id=whatever],body,[whatever]"
```

Though not as harmful as `window.name`, it might be worth fixing.

Comment: Also, is this possible without using an iFrame?

Comment: @MichaelBlake `window.name` can also be set via the second argument of `window.open`. Since frames can be hidden, it's unlikely that `window.open(url, name)` will be used for such an attack. Furthermore, Chrome seems to clear `window.name` with `window.open`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to attack vectors described in the first answer, and attacker could set

```
window.name="<script>alert(1)</script>";
```

On their malicious webpage and redirect the victim to your webpage. Because window.name persists across page load, this would also be an xss attack vector.